# Redirect to home page with arguments after submiting form in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I am trying to add details of students,which is submitted using django  & 'POST' method.
On submission I save the details in my 'py' file. After that I want to redirect to home page.
Earlier I used

```
return render_to_response("home.html",{ "edit":0,"msg":'saved'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But on each refreshing of the home page it will insert data to table.
Then I tried to used "HttpResponseRedirect" , but it will not support argument passing.
How can I resolve this ?

add.py

```
stud = student(name=request.POST['studname'])
stud.save()
return render_to_response("home.html",{ "edit":0,"msg":'saved'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

student.html

```
<form id = "addForm" name = "addForm" action = "" method = 'POST' >
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Name.</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="studname" id="studname"></td> 
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: make name as unigue=true in django models

Comment: When you get your answer, mark it as verified.

Comment: but the name,class,etc can be same for different students

Comment: @user123, agreed with the name, class, etc can be same for different students. You do not have to worry about making anything unique, but only worry about redirect behavior as shown in my answer

Answer (score 5):

You should look into [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Basically,

1. Ensure, you have a POST method that handles the post
2. Then REDIRECT the user to a specific page.
3. Which then has a GET request to serve the page.

Here is what you can think:

Use Django's [**redirect**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
def submitting_student(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
        stud = student(name=request.POST['studname'])
        stud.save()
        return redirect("home.html", { "edit":0, "msg":'saved' })

   return render_to_response("student.html")
```

Here is another post on the same topic of [PRG pattern](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/10/19/post-redirect-get-prg-pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the request is a post first in add.py

eg.

```
msg = ""

   if request.method == "POST":
        stud = student(name=request.POST['studname'])
        stud.save()

        msg = "saved"

   return render_to_response("home.html",{ "edit":0,"msg":msg}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I checked 'request.method' but after submission on each refresh of 'home' page I am getting POST method.So it is inserting data as much as the time I am saving